# how best to handling ruby nils, and should CSV return empty strings or nils?

Tags: ruby, csv, null

in a pairing session we came up against the issue of how to handle ruby nils and whether csv parsing (via ruby's CSV package) would be better if it passed back empty strings ...

You can see the specs we were creating here:

https://github.com/mtc2013/LocalSupport/blob/seed-refactoring/spec/models/organization_spec.rb

We're trying to process data from a text file in csv form, and we have the issue that the processing we do to extract postcodes will barf if the incoming element is a nil, so we have these sad paths:

```
expect(Organization.extract_postcode('HARROW BAPTIST CHURCH, COLLEGE ROAD, HARROW')).to eq(nil)
expect(Organization.extract_postcode(nil)).to eq(nil)
```

Actually this extract_postcode method could return an empty string I guess.  You can see the code we implemented here:

https://github.com/mtc2013/LocalSupport/blob/seed-refactoring/app/models/organization.rb

```
def self.extract_postcode(address_with_trailing_postcode)  
    match = address_with_trailing_postcode && address_with_trailing_postcode.match(/\s*(\w\w\d\s* \d\w\w)/)
    match && match[1]
  end
```

we're still feeling this is a little ugly.  In something like Objective C you can just call methods on the nil object and they return nil.  In ruby they throw an exception, so we check with this "match && match[1]" operation, but is this recommended?

Another approach might be to ensure that the CSV parsing always generated empty strings rather than nils, but it feels like we still need to protect our code against nils being passed in.

I guess our ultimate question is what's the ruby way here?  If you have a method should it just throw errors when it gets passed a nil?  Or should you catch them and just return nil?  Or an empty string if it's a string manipulation method?

I guess if it's recommended to throw nil errors then we should just focus on fixing up our CSV parsing to treat missing elements as empty strings ... or maybe the better approach would be to catch the nil errors and re-throw them with our own custom error messages?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you not using Ruby's built-in `CSV`?

Comment: `nil.to_s` results in an empty string, so maybe a well-placed `to_s`could solve the issue.

Comment: Neil - we are using CSV to get the data out of CSV format

Comment: Steenslag - great suggestion - will have to try that ...

Comment: @steenslag - we went with your suggestion and that has simplified alot of the code - if you want to add that as an answer I could give you a tick?

Answer (score 2):

I think your `extract_postcode` returning `nil` is accurate. When there is no postcode to extract from an address, it is a good representation. If the method returned an empty string instead, and you expect caller to cope with that, the calling code would still need to check the contents directly for a decision on how to process that value (it isn't a valid or useful postcode after all). An empty string postcode is only useful to you in that you can safely call String methods on it, but that is ignoring the fact that you don't actually have postcode data - a fact your code will have to acknowledge sooner or later.

With a method name like `extract_postcode` I think it would also be reasonable to raise an exception when there was no postcode data. But exception handling might be a more awkward way of getting the logical flow you need.

If you are storing the data extracted elsewhere, it might be worth considering aligning the returned value with how that is set up. If your database stores nulls in the postcode column to represent "no postcode", then a nil value in Ruby is a better match to that than an empty string. Doing this will save you code mapping between representations.

Ultimately there isn't a "Ruby way" here AFAIK. Being self-consistent, at least in the context of whatever layer in your overall application this code operates within, will give you the best returns.

Comment: many thanks for the detailed suggestion.  After various refactoring we now have a parse_address method:

https://github.com/tansaku/LocalSupport/blob/master/app/models/organization.rb

which is of course screaming for an extract class refactoring, but we've put that off til later. @steenslags to_s is very helpful.  having to deal with match being nil is still very strange ... the match.length = 4 is actually a hangover from before when we through we could match the regex two ways - could lose that now - but would love match[1] to return nil if match was nil ...

Comment: Found a great talk that recommends the to_s method amongst other things: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8J0j2xJFgQ